# How to get reference to the sender on itext event handler

Tags: c#, events, event-handling, itext

How can I get the object sender in iTextSharp event handler OnStarPage?

```
class _Events : PdfPageEventHelper
{

    public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        base.OnStartPage(writer, document);
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("TITULO DE TODOS LOS REPORTES\n\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 9, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD));
        paragraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        document.Add(paragraph);
      //I NEED THE OBJECT HERE

     }
}
```

Comment: You have a reference to the page (`this`) what else do you need?

Comment: I have reference to this event handler from 5 classes, how can i know which class call the event?

Comment: 1.) Itext page events are not designed to allow `document.Add` operations in them. Add to the direct content in them only. 2.) `OnStartPage` is not designed for document changes at all, only for book keeping purposes. 3.) Please explain your user case requiring you to know the event source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve it. If someone need it:

class _Events : PdfPageEventHelper
{

```
public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
{
    base.OnStartPage(writer, document);
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("GENERAL TITLE\n\n", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 9, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD));
    paragraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    document.Add(paragraph);

    paragraph = new Paragraph(pintaTitulo(), FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 9, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD));
    document.Add(paragraph);
 }
```

public virtual string pintaTitulo() { return "000"; }

}

And then:

```
class _EventsInherited : _Events
{
    public _EventsInherited(){}

    public override string pintaTitulo()
    {
        return "subTitle"; 
    }
}
```

And suscribe the document class to : _EventsInherited

Comment: As mentioned above: Itext(Sharp) page events are not designed to allow `document.Add` operations in them. It may look like working alright and then fail you in funny ways.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't change the method signature, you'll need another mechanism to show which page sent a document.

One dumb, but fairly effective way to do so is to keep a dictionary in some shared object that maps the page to the document.

```
    Dictionary<Page, Document>.
```

How are you calling the code?

Comment: In 5 different classes (5 different reports), I suscribe to event handler like this:

PdfPageEventHelper pageeventhandler = new _Events();
            wri.PageEvent = pageeventhandler;

I need to know which class call the event.

Answer (score 0):

Create a parameter in your `_Events` class. Pass the name of the class to the event handler as a parameter of the constructor.